# how to customize jQuery Password Strength indicator location

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using jQuery Password Strength plugin for Twitter Bootstrap to display password strength. when we enter new password, the indicator will display the strength of it. i want to display the password strength indicator inside of  the custom div. the jQuery Password Strength plugin is like this

```js
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var options = {
                onLoad: function () {
                    $('#messages').text('Start typing password');
                },
                onKeyUp: function (evt) {
                    $(evt.target).pwstrength("outputErrorList");
                }
            };
            $('#new_password').pwstrength(options);
        });

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var options = {
            errors: [],
            // Options
            minChar: 8,
            errorMessages: {
                password_to_short: "The Password is too short",
                same_as_username: "Your password cannot be the same as your username"
            },
            scores: [17, 26, 40, 50],
            verdicts: ["Weak", "Normal", "Medium", "Strong", "Very Strong"],
            showVerdicts: true,
            raisePower: 1.4,
            usernameField: "#username",
            onLoad: undefined,
            onKeyUp: undefined,
            viewports: {
                progress: undefined,
                verdict: undefined,
                errors: undefined
            },
            // Rules stuff
            ruleScores: {
                wordNotEmail: -100,
                wordLength: -100,
                wordSimilarToUsername: -100,
                wordLowercase: 1,
                wordUppercase: 3,
                wordOneNumber: 3,
                wordThreeNumbers: 5,
                wordOneSpecialChar: 3,
                wordTwoSpecialChar: 5,
                wordUpperLowerCombo: 2,
                wordLetterNumberCombo: 2,
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: 2
            },
            rules: {
                wordNotEmail: true,
                wordLength: true,
                wordSimilarToUsername: true,
                wordLowercase: true,
                wordUppercase: true,
                wordOneNumber: true,
                wordThreeNumbers: true,
                wordOneSpecialChar: true,
                wordTwoSpecialChar: true,
                wordUpperLowerCombo: true,
                wordLetterNumberCombo: true,
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: true
            },
            validationRules: {
                wordNotEmail: function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i) && score;
                },
                wordLength: function (options, word, score) {
                    var wordlen = word.length,
                        lenScore = Math.pow(wordlen, options.raisePower);
                    if (wordlen < options.minChar) {
                        lenScore = (lenScore + score);
                        options.errors.push(options.errorMessages.password_to_short);
                    }
                    return lenScore;
                },
                wordSimilarToUsername: function (options, word, score) {
                    var username = $(options.usernameField).val();
                    if (username && word.toLowerCase().match(username.toLowerCase())) {
                        options.errors.push(options.errorMessages.same_as_username);
                        return score;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                wordLowercase: function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/[a-z]/) && score;
                },
                wordUppercase: function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/[A-Z]/) && score;
                },
                wordOneNumber : function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/\d+/) && score;
                },
                wordThreeNumbers : function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/(.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])/) && score;
                },
                wordOneSpecialChar : function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~]/) && score;
                },
                wordTwoSpecialChar : function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/(.*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~].*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~])/) && score;
                },
                wordUpperLowerCombo : function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/) && score;
                },
                wordLetterNumberCombo : function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && word.match(/([0-9])/) && score;
                },
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo : function (options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9].*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~])|([!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~].*[a-zA-Z0-9])/) && score;
                }
            }
        },

        setProgressBar = function ($el, score) {
            var options = $el.data("pwstrength"),
                progressbar = options.progressbar,
                $verdict;

            if (options.showVerdicts) {
                if (options.viewports.verdict) {
                    $verdict = $(options.viewports.verdict).find(".password-verdict");
                } else {
                    $verdict = $el.parent().find(".password-verdict");
                    if ($verdict.length === 0) {
                        $verdict = $('<span class="password-verdict"></span>');
                        $verdict.insertAfter($el);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (score < options.scores[0]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "5%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[0]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[0] && score < options.scores[1]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "25%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[1]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[1] && score < options.scores[2]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "50%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[2]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[2] && score < options.scores[3]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "75%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[3]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[3]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-success").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "100%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[4]);
                }
            }
        },

        calculateScore = function ($el) {
            var self = this,
                word = $el.val(),
                totalScore = 0,
                options = $el.data("pwstrength");

            $.each(options.rules, function (rule, active) {
                if (active === true) {
                    var score = options.ruleScores[rule],
                        result = options.validationRules[rule](options, word, score);
                    if (result) {
                        totalScore += result;
                    }
                }
            });
            setProgressBar($el, totalScore);
            return totalScore;
        },

        progressWidget = function () {
            return '<div class="progress"><div class="bar"></div></div>';
        },

        methods = {
            init: function (settings) {
                var self = this,
                    allOptions = $.extend(options, settings);

                return this.each(function (idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el),
                        progressbar,
                        verdict;

                    $el.data("pwstrength", allOptions);

                    $el.on("keyup", function (event) {
                        var options = $el.data("pwstrength");
                        options.errors = [];
                        calculateScore.call(self, $el);
                        if ($.isFunction(options.onKeyUp)) {
                            options.onKeyUp(event);
                        }
                    });

                    progressbar = $(progressWidget());
                    if (allOptions.viewports.progress) {
                        $(allOptions.viewports.progress).append(progressbar);
                    } else {
                        progressbar.insertAfter($el);
                    }
                    progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "0%");
                    $el.data("pwstrength").progressbar = progressbar;

                    if (allOptions.showVerdicts) {
                        verdict = $('<span class="password-verdict">' + allOptions.verdicts[0] + '</span>');
                        if (allOptions.viewports.verdict) {
                            $(allOptions.viewports.verdict).append(verdict);
                        } else {
                            verdict.insertAfter($el);
                        }
                    }

                    if ($.isFunction(allOptions.onLoad)) {
                        allOptions.onLoad();
                    }
                });
            },

            destroy: function () {
                this.each(function (idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el);
                    $el.parent().find("span.password-verdict").remove();
                    $el.parent().find("div.progress").remove();
                    $el.parent().find("ul.error-list").remove();
                    $el.removeData("pwstrength");
                });
            },

            forceUpdate: function () {
                var self = this;
                this.each(function (idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el),
                        options = $el.data("pwstrength");
                    options.errors = [];
                    calculateScore.call(self, $el);
                });
            },

            outputErrorList: function () {
                this.each(function (idx, el) {
                    var output = '<ul class="error-list">',
                        $el = $(el),
                        errors = $el.data("pwstrength").errors,
                        viewports = $el.data("pwstrength").viewports,
                        verdict;
                    $el.parent().find("ul.error-list").remove();

                    if (errors.length > 0) {
                        $.each(errors, function (i, item) {
                            output += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
                        });
                        output += '</ul>';
                        if (viewports.errors) {
                            $(viewports.errors).html(output);
                        } else {
                            output = $(output);
                            verdict = $el.parent().find("span.password-verdict");
                            if (verdict.length > 0) {
                                el = verdict;
                            }
                            output.insertAfter(el);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },

            addRule: function (name, method, score, active) {
                this.each(function (idx, el) {
                    var options = $(el).data("pwstrength");
                    options.rules[name] = active;
                    options.ruleScores[name] = score;
                    options.validationRules[name] = method;
                });
            },

            changeScore: function (rule, score) {
                this.each(function (idx, el) {
                    $(el).data("pwstrength").ruleScores[rule] = score;
                });
            },

            ruleActive: function (rule, active) {
                this.each(function (idx, el) {
                    $(el).data("pwstrength").rules[rule] = active;
                });
            }
        };

    $.fn.pwstrength = function (method) {
        var result;
        if (methods[method]) {
            result = methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
            result = methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error("Method " +  method + " does not exist on jQuery.pwstrength");
        }
        return result;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0;} to{background-position:0 0;}}@-moz-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0;} to{background-position:0 0;}}@-ms-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0;} to{background-position:0 0;}}@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:0 0;} to{background-position:40px 0;}}@keyframes progress-bar-stripes{from{background-position:40px 0;} to{background-position:0 0;}}.progress{overflow:hidden;height:20px;margin-bottom:20px;background-color:#f7f7f7;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f5f5f5), to(#f9f9f9));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff5f5f5', endColorstr='#fff9f9f9', GradientType=0);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);-webkit-border-radius:4px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;}
.progress .bar{width:0%;height:100%;color:#ffffff;float:left;font-size:12px;text-align:center;text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);background-color:#0e90d2;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#149bdf), to(#0480be));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #149bdf, #0480be);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff149bdf', endColorstr='#ff0480be', GradientType=0);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-transition:width 0.6s ease;-moz-transition:width 0.6s ease;-o-transition:width 0.6s ease;transition:width 0.6s ease;}
.progress .bar+.bar{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);-moz-box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);box-shadow:inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);}
.progress-striped .bar{background-color:#149bdf;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);-webkit-background-size:40px 40px;-moz-background-size:40px 40px;-o-background-size:40px 40px;background-size:40px 40px;}
.progress.active .bar{-webkit-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;-moz-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;-ms-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;-o-animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;animation:progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;}
.progress-danger .bar,.progress .bar-danger{background-color:#dd514c;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ee5f5b), to(#c43c35));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffee5f5b', endColorstr='#ffc43c35', GradientType=0);}
.progress-danger.progress-striped .bar,.progress-striped .bar-danger{background-color:#ee5f5b;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);}
.progress-success .bar,.progress .bar-success{background-color:#5eb95e;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#62c462), to(#57a957));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #62c462, #57a957);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff62c462', endColorstr='#ff57a957', GradientType=0);}
.progress-success.progress-striped .bar,.progress-striped .bar-success{background-color:#62c462;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);}
.progress-info .bar,.progress .bar-info{background-color:#4bb1cf;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#5bc0de), to(#339bb9));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #5bc0de, #339bb9);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5bc0de', endColorstr='#ff339bb9', GradientType=0);}
.progress-info.progress-striped .bar,.progress-striped .bar-info{background-color:#5bc0de;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);}
.progress-warning .bar,.progress .bar-warning{background-color:#faa732;background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fbb450), to(#f89406));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbb450, #f89406);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);}
.progress-warning.progress-striped .bar,.progress-striped .bar-warning{background-color:#fbb450;background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);background-image:linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please type in your password</legend>
    Current Password: <input type="password" id="current_password" /><br />
    New Password: <input type="password" id="new_password" />
    Confirm Password: <input type="password" id="confirm_password" /><br />
     Password Strength: <div id="password-indicator"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

I would appreciate any help where we can customize the indicator's location and display the password strength indicator inside of the custom div *password-indicator*

```
Password Strength: <div id="password-indicator"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet below shows exactly what you want.

Explanation : I just added two new options : `verdictLocation` and `progressBarLocation`. These two new options should contain the selector after which the verdict and the progress bar are moved respectively.

Thus, I just added

```
<div id="verdict-location"></div>
<div id="progress-bar-location"></div>
```

to set the new verdict and progress bar locations.

*Note* : The errors are currently set after the verdict. If you want, you can follow the same logic and implement an error location (ie add another option). It's up to you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        onLoad: function() {
            $('#messages').text('Start typing password');
        },
        onKeyUp: function(evt) {
            $(evt.target).pwstrength("outputErrorList");
        }
    };
    $('#new_password').pwstrength(options);
});

(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var options = {
            errors: [],
            // Options
           
            verdictLocation: '#verdict-location', // New option
            progressBarLocation: '#progress-bar-location', // New option

            minChar: 8,
            errorMessages: {
                password_to_short: "The Password is too short",
                same_as_username: "Your password cannot be the same as your username"
            },
            scores: [17, 26, 40, 50],
            verdicts: ["Weak", "Normal", "Medium", "Strong", "Very Strong"],
            showVerdicts: true,
            raisePower: 1.4,
            usernameField: "#username",
            onLoad: undefined,
            onKeyUp: undefined,
            viewports: {
                progress: undefined,
                verdict: undefined,
                errors: undefined
            },
            // Rules stuff
            ruleScores: {
                wordNotEmail: -100,
                wordLength: -100,
                wordSimilarToUsername: -100,
                wordLowercase: 1,
                wordUppercase: 3,
                wordOneNumber: 3,
                wordThreeNumbers: 5,
                wordOneSpecialChar: 3,
                wordTwoSpecialChar: 5,
                wordUpperLowerCombo: 2,
                wordLetterNumberCombo: 2,
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: 2
            },
            rules: {
                wordNotEmail: true,
                wordLength: true,
                wordSimilarToUsername: true,
                wordLowercase: true,
                wordUppercase: true,
                wordOneNumber: true,
                wordThreeNumbers: true,
                wordOneSpecialChar: true,
                wordTwoSpecialChar: true,
                wordUpperLowerCombo: true,
                wordLetterNumberCombo: true,
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: true
            },
            validationRules: {
                wordNotEmail: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i) && score;
                },
                wordLength: function(options, word, score) {
                    var wordlen = word.length,
                        lenScore = Math.pow(wordlen, options.raisePower);
                    if (wordlen < options.minChar) {
                        lenScore = (lenScore + score);
                        options.errors.push(options.errorMessages.password_to_short);
                    }
                    return lenScore;
                },
                wordSimilarToUsername: function(options, word, score) {
                    var username = $(options.usernameField).val();
                    if (username && word.toLowerCase().match(username.toLowerCase())) {
                        options.errors.push(options.errorMessages.same_as_username);
                        return score;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                wordLowercase: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/[a-z]/) && score;
                },
                wordUppercase: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/[A-Z]/) && score;
                },
                wordOneNumber: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/\d+/) && score;
                },
                wordThreeNumbers: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/(.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])/) && score;
                },
                wordOneSpecialChar: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~]/) && score;
                },
                wordTwoSpecialChar: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/(.*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~].*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~])/) && score;
                },
                wordUpperLowerCombo: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/) && score;
                },
                wordLetterNumberCombo: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && word.match(/([0-9])/) && score;
                },
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9].*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~])|([!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~].*[a-zA-Z0-9])/) && score;
                }
            }
        },

        setProgressBar = function($el, score) {
            var options = $el.data("pwstrength"),
                progressbar = options.progressbar,
                $verdict;

            if (options.showVerdicts) {
                if (options.viewports.verdict) {
                    $verdict = $(options.viewports.verdict).find(".password-verdict");
                } else {
                    $verdict = $el.parent().find(".password-verdict");
                    if ($verdict.length === 0) {
                        $verdict = $('<span class="password-verdict"></span>');
                        $verdict.insertAfter(options.verdictLocation); //Changed $el to option
                    }
                }
            }

            if (score < options.scores[0]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "5%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[0]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[0] && score < options.scores[1]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "25%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[1]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[1] && score < options.scores[2]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "50%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[2]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[2] && score < options.scores[3]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "75%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[3]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[3]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-success").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "100%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[4]);
                }
            }
        },

        calculateScore = function($el) {
            var self = this,
                word = $el.val(),
                totalScore = 0,
                options = $el.data("pwstrength");

            $.each(options.rules, function(rule, active) {
                if (active === true) {
                    var score = options.ruleScores[rule],
                        result = options.validationRules[rule](options, word, score);
                    if (result) {
                        totalScore += result;
                    }
                }
            });
            setProgressBar($el, totalScore);
            return totalScore;
        },

        progressWidget = function() {
            return '<div id="password-indicator"><div class="progress"><div class="bar"></div></div></div>';
        },

        methods = {
            init: function(settings) {
                var self = this,
                    allOptions = $.extend(options, settings);

                return this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el),
                        progressbar,
                        verdict;

                    $el.data("pwstrength", allOptions);

                    $el.on("keyup", function(event) {
                        var options = $el.data("pwstrength");
                        options.errors = [];
                        calculateScore.call(self, $el);
                        if ($.isFunction(options.onKeyUp)) {
                            options.onKeyUp(event);
                        }
                    });

                    progressbar = $(progressWidget());
                    if (allOptions.viewports.progress) {
                        $(allOptions.viewports.progress).append(progressbar);
                    } else {
                        progressbar.insertAfter(options.progressBarLocation);
                    }
                    progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "0%");
                    $el.data("pwstrength").progressbar = progressbar;

                    if (allOptions.showVerdicts) {
                        verdict = $('<span class="password-verdict">' + allOptions.verdicts[0] + '</span>');
                        if (allOptions.viewports.verdict) {
                            $(allOptions.viewports.verdict).append(verdict);
                        } else {
                            verdict.insertAfter(options.verdictLocation); //  Changed
                        }
                    }

                    if ($.isFunction(allOptions.onLoad)) {
                        allOptions.onLoad();
                    }
                });
            },

            destroy: function() {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el);
                    $el.parent().find("span.password-verdict").remove();
                    $el.parent().find("div.progress").remove();
                    $el.parent().find("ul.error-list").remove();
                    $el.removeData("pwstrength");
                });
            },

            forceUpdate: function() {
                var self = this;
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el),
                        options = $el.data("pwstrength");
                    options.errors = [];
                    calculateScore.call(self, $el);
                });
            },

            outputErrorList: function() {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var output = '<ul class="error-list">',
                        $el = $(el),
                        errors = $el.data("pwstrength").errors,
                        viewports = $el.data("pwstrength").viewports,
                        verdict;
                    $el.parent().find("ul.error-list").remove();

                    if (errors.length > 0) {
                        $.each(errors, function(i, item) {
                            output += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
                        });
                        output += '</ul>';
                        if (viewports.errors) {
                            $(viewports.errors).html(output);
                        } else {
                            output = $(output);
                            verdict = $el.parent().find("span.password-verdict");
                            if (verdict.length > 0) {
                                el = verdict;
                            }
                            output.insertAfter(el);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },

            addRule: function(name, method, score, active) {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var options = $(el).data("pwstrength");
                    options.rules[name] = active;
                    options.ruleScores[name] = score;
                    options.validationRules[name] = method;
                });
            },

            changeScore: function(rule, score) {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    $(el).data("pwstrength").ruleScores[rule] = score;
                });
            },

            ruleActive: function(rule, active) {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    $(el).data("pwstrength").rules[rule] = active;
                });
            }
        };

    $.fn.pwstrength = function(method) {
        var result;
        if (methods[method]) {
            result = methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
            result = methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.pwstrength");
        }
        return result;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
}
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
.progress {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f5f5f5), to(#f9f9f9));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff5f5f5', endColorstr='#fff9f9f9', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.progress .bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #0e90d2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#149bdf), to(#0480be));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff149bdf', endColorstr='#ff0480be', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
.progress .bar+.bar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.progress-striped .bar {
  background-color: #149bdf;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
  -moz-background-size: 40px 40px;
  -o-background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress.active .bar {
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
.progress-danger .bar,
.progress .bar-danger {
  background-color: #dd514c;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ee5f5b), to(#c43c35));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffee5f5b', endColorstr='#ffc43c35', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-danger.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-danger {
  background-color: #ee5f5b;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-success .bar,
.progress .bar-success {
  background-color: #5eb95e;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#62c462), to(#57a957));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff62c462', endColorstr='#ff57a957', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-success.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-success {
  background-color: #62c462;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-info .bar,
.progress .bar-info {
  background-color: #4bb1cf;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#5bc0de), to(#339bb9));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5bc0de', endColorstr='#ff339bb9', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-info.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-info {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-warning .bar,
.progress .bar-warning {
  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fbb450), to(#f89406));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-warning.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-warning {
  background-color: #fbb450;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please type in your password</legend>
    Current Password:
    <input type="password" id="current_password" />
    <br />New Password:
    <input type="password" id="new_password" />Confirm Password:
    <input type="password" id="confirm_password" />
    <br />Password Strength:
    <p> ----------------------------------------------------------</p>
    <p> Let's move indicator and progress bar after this paragraph</p>
    <p> ----------------------------------------------------------</p>
    <div id="verdict-location"></div>
    <div id="progress-bar-location"></div>
    
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        onLoad: function() {
            $('#messages').text('Start typing password');
        },
        onKeyUp: function(evt) {
            $(evt.target).pwstrength("outputErrorList");
        }
    };
    $('#new_password').pwstrength(options);
});

(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var options = {
            errors: [],
            // Options
           
            verdictLocation: '#verdict-location', // New option
            progressBarLocation: '#progress-bar-location', // New option

            minChar: 8,
            errorMessages: {
                password_to_short: "The Password is too short",
                same_as_username: "Your password cannot be the same as your username"
            },
            scores: [17, 26, 40, 50],
            verdicts: ["Weak", "Normal", "Medium", "Strong", "Very Strong"],
            showVerdicts: true,
            raisePower: 1.4,
            usernameField: "#username",
            onLoad: undefined,
            onKeyUp: undefined,
            viewports: {
                progress: undefined,
                verdict: undefined,
                errors: undefined
            },
            // Rules stuff
            ruleScores: {
                wordNotEmail: -100,
                wordLength: -100,
                wordSimilarToUsername: -100,
                wordLowercase: 1,
                wordUppercase: 3,
                wordOneNumber: 3,
                wordThreeNumbers: 5,
                wordOneSpecialChar: 3,
                wordTwoSpecialChar: 5,
                wordUpperLowerCombo: 2,
                wordLetterNumberCombo: 2,
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: 2
            },
            rules: {
                wordNotEmail: true,
                wordLength: true,
                wordSimilarToUsername: true,
                wordLowercase: true,
                wordUppercase: true,
                wordOneNumber: true,
                wordThreeNumbers: true,
                wordOneSpecialChar: true,
                wordTwoSpecialChar: true,
                wordUpperLowerCombo: true,
                wordLetterNumberCombo: true,
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: true
            },
            validationRules: {
                wordNotEmail: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/^([\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`{\|\}\~]+@((((([a-z0-9]{1}[a-z0-9\-]{0,62}[a-z0-9]{1})|[a-z])\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(\:\d{1,5})?)$/i) && score;
                },
                wordLength: function(options, word, score) {
                    var wordlen = word.length,
                        lenScore = Math.pow(wordlen, options.raisePower);
                    if (wordlen < options.minChar) {
                        lenScore = (lenScore + score);
                        options.errors.push(options.errorMessages.password_to_short);
                    }
                    return lenScore;
                },
                wordSimilarToUsername: function(options, word, score) {
                    var username = $(options.usernameField).val();
                    if (username && word.toLowerCase().match(username.toLowerCase())) {
                        options.errors.push(options.errorMessages.same_as_username);
                        return score;
                    }
                    return true;
                },
                wordLowercase: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/[a-z]/) && score;
                },
                wordUppercase: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/[A-Z]/) && score;
                },
                wordOneNumber: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/\d+/) && score;
                },
                wordThreeNumbers: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/(.*[0-9].*[0-9].*[0-9])/) && score;
                },
                wordOneSpecialChar: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/.[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~]/) && score;
                },
                wordTwoSpecialChar: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/(.*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~].*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~])/) && score;
                },
                wordUpperLowerCombo: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-z].*[A-Z])|([A-Z].*[a-z])/) && score;
                },
                wordLetterNumberCombo: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-zA-Z])/) && word.match(/([0-9])/) && score;
                },
                wordLetterNumberCharCombo: function(options, word, score) {
                    return word.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9].*[!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~])|([!,@,#,$,%,\^,&,*,?,_,~].*[a-zA-Z0-9])/) && score;
                }
            }
        },

        setProgressBar = function($el, score) {
            var options = $el.data("pwstrength"),
                progressbar = options.progressbar,
                $verdict;

            if (options.showVerdicts) {
                if (options.viewports.verdict) {
                    $verdict = $(options.viewports.verdict).find(".password-verdict");
                } else {
                    $verdict = $el.parent().find(".password-verdict");
                    if ($verdict.length === 0) {
                        $verdict = $('<span class="password-verdict"></span>');
                        $verdict.insertAfter(options.verdictLocation); //Changed $el to option
                    }
                }
            }

            if (score < options.scores[0]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "5%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[0]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[0] && score < options.scores[1]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "25%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[1]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[1] && score < options.scores[2]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "50%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[2]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[2] && score < options.scores[3]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger").removeClass("progress-success");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "75%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[3]);
                }
            } else if (score >= options.scores[3]) {
                progressbar.addClass("progress-success").removeClass("progress-warning").removeClass("progress-danger");
                progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "100%");
                if (options.showVerdicts) {
                    $verdict.text(options.verdicts[4]);
                }
            }
        },

        calculateScore = function($el) {
            var self = this,
                word = $el.val(),
                totalScore = 0,
                options = $el.data("pwstrength");

            $.each(options.rules, function(rule, active) {
                if (active === true) {
                    var score = options.ruleScores[rule],
                        result = options.validationRules[rule](options, word, score);
                    if (result) {
                        totalScore += result;
                    }
                }
            });
            setProgressBar($el, totalScore);
            return totalScore;
        },

        progressWidget = function() {
            return '<div id="password-indicator"><div class="progress"><div class="bar"></div></div></div>';
        },

        methods = {
            init: function(settings) {
                var self = this,
                    allOptions = $.extend(options, settings);

                return this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el),
                        progressbar,
                        verdict;

                    $el.data("pwstrength", allOptions);

                    $el.on("keyup", function(event) {
                        var options = $el.data("pwstrength");
                        options.errors = [];
                        calculateScore.call(self, $el);
                        if ($.isFunction(options.onKeyUp)) {
                            options.onKeyUp(event);
                        }
                    });

                    progressbar = $(progressWidget());
                    if (allOptions.viewports.progress) {
                        $(allOptions.viewports.progress).append(progressbar);
                    } else {
                        progressbar.insertAfter(options.progressBarLocation);
                    }
                    progressbar.find(".bar").css("width", "0%");
                    $el.data("pwstrength").progressbar = progressbar;

                    if (allOptions.showVerdicts) {
                        verdict = $('<span class="password-verdict">' + allOptions.verdicts[0] + '</span>');
                        if (allOptions.viewports.verdict) {
                            $(allOptions.viewports.verdict).append(verdict);
                        } else {
                            verdict.insertAfter(options.verdictLocation); //  Changed
                        }
                    }

                    if ($.isFunction(allOptions.onLoad)) {
                        allOptions.onLoad();
                    }
                });
            },

            destroy: function() {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el);
                    $el.parent().find("span.password-verdict").remove();
                    $el.parent().find("div.progress").remove();
                    $el.parent().find("ul.error-list").remove();
                    $el.removeData("pwstrength");
                });
            },

            forceUpdate: function() {
                var self = this;
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var $el = $(el),
                        options = $el.data("pwstrength");
                    options.errors = [];
                    calculateScore.call(self, $el);
                });
            },

            outputErrorList: function() {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var output = '<ul class="error-list">',
                        $el = $(el),
                        errors = $el.data("pwstrength").errors,
                        viewports = $el.data("pwstrength").viewports,
                        verdict;
                    $el.parent().find("ul.error-list").remove();

                    if (errors.length > 0) {
                        $.each(errors, function(i, item) {
                            output += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
                        });
                        output += '</ul>';
                        if (viewports.errors) {
                            $(viewports.errors).html(output);
                        } else {
                            output = $(output);
                            verdict = $el.parent().find("span.password-verdict");
                            if (verdict.length > 0) {
                                el = verdict;
                            }
                            output.insertAfter(el);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },

            addRule: function(name, method, score, active) {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    var options = $(el).data("pwstrength");
                    options.rules[name] = active;
                    options.ruleScores[name] = score;
                    options.validationRules[name] = method;
                });
            },

            changeScore: function(rule, score) {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    $(el).data("pwstrength").ruleScores[rule] = score;
                });
            },

            ruleActive: function(rule, active) {
                this.each(function(idx, el) {
                    $(el).data("pwstrength").rules[rule] = active;
                });
            }
        };

    $.fn.pwstrength = function(method) {
        var result;
        if (methods[method]) {
            result = methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
            result = methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.pwstrength");
        }
        return result;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
}
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
  from {
    background-position: 40px 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
.progress {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f5f5f5), to(#f9f9f9));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5, #f9f9f9);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff5f5f5', endColorstr='#fff9f9f9', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.progress .bar {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background-color: #0e90d2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#149bdf), to(#0480be));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #149bdf, #0480be);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff149bdf', endColorstr='#ff0480be', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
.progress .bar+.bar {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
.progress-striped .bar {
  background-color: #149bdf;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
  -moz-background-size: 40px 40px;
  -o-background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress.active .bar {
  -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
  animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
.progress-danger .bar,
.progress .bar-danger {
  background-color: #dd514c;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ee5f5b), to(#c43c35));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffee5f5b', endColorstr='#ffc43c35', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-danger.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-danger {
  background-color: #ee5f5b;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-success .bar,
.progress .bar-success {
  background-color: #5eb95e;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#62c462), to(#57a957));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62c462, #57a957);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff62c462', endColorstr='#ff57a957', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-success.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-success {
  background-color: #62c462;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-info .bar,
.progress .bar-info {
  background-color: #4bb1cf;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#5bc0de), to(#339bb9));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5bc0de, #339bb9);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5bc0de', endColorstr='#ff339bb9', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-info.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-info {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-warning .bar,
.progress .bar-warning {
  background-color: #faa732;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fbb450), to(#f89406));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbb450', endColorstr='#fff89406', GradientType=0);
}
.progress-warning.progress-striped .bar,
.progress-striped .bar-warning {
  background-color: #fbb450;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(0.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.25, transparent), color-stop(0.5, transparent), color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)), color-stop(0.75, transparent), to(transparent));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Please type in your password</legend>
    <br />Current Password:<br />
    <input type="password" id="current_password" />
    <br />New Password:
    <br /><input type="password" id="new_password" />
     <br />Confirm Password:<br />
    <input type="password" id="confirm_password" /><br /><br />
     Password Strength:
    
    <div id="verdict-location"></div>
    <div id="progress-bar-location"></div>
    
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

More accurate by aligning input fields for users to see clearly.